# Spring StateMachne support for UML submachines

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

Is there a **stable** version of Spring state-machine that supports the **UML sub-machines**? My state diagram has become so big and complex and I'm searching solutions for utilizing sub-machines in my state diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `1.2.0.RC1` and give feedback on it. We'll get `1.2.0.RELEASE` out before xmas, thought I'll do `RC2` before it as I like final RC to be same as release(what comes for a core code).

Comment: Using version: 1.2.0.RC1 model: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-uml/src/test/resources/org/springframework/statemachine/uml/simple-submachine.uml Sub-machine works but "eventNotAccepted" method called incorrectly on each event send

Comment: Using version: 1.2.0.RC1 model:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-uml/src/test/resources/org/springframework/statemachine/uml/simple-submachine.uml If i add a new state after s2 in parent diagram, all sub-machine of s2 will be ignored!

Comment: Would you mind creating gh issues for things you've found.

Comment: btw, uml submachines are used in `simple-submachineref`, `simple-submachine` just defines sub-states.